# Python re.findall non-greedy result

Tags: python, regex, findall, non-greedy

I'm trying to get only "Text3" part with the following code:

```
import re
stringtotest = "begin:Text1<wrong>Text2<wrong>Text3<right>Text4<wrong>"
right = re.findall("<wrong>(.+?)<right>",stringtotest)
>>> right
['Text2<wrong>Text3']
```

Why Python gives me Text2 as well? How to tell him I want only the part after the nearest "wrong"? Thank you.

Comment: This question has little to do with greedy vs non-greedy, since even a non-greedy match would fail to produce the desired result. The asker is using a lazy match, which is even less aggressive.

Comment: You are absolutely right.

Comment: Sorry, I'm new to Python. What if I have stringtotest = "begin\r\nText1\r\n<wrong>\r\nText2\r\nsome more text\r\n<wrong>\r\nText3\r\n<right>\r\nText4\r\n<wrong>"  How can I get only the part before <right>?

Answer (score 4):

The dot `.` matches anything. You can use a negated character class to restrict the match:

```
<wrong>([^<]+?)<right>
```

If you want to get the middle section without the outer tags, use lookaheads and lookbehinds to assert the position of the tags:

```
(?<=<wrong>)([^<]+?)(?=<right>)
```

Comment: You should not use lazy matching in here, as greedy matching can't ever exceed the right "boundary here". Greedily it takes one step to match the characters between closing `>` and opening `<`, while lazily it checks every character on its own. Note that many regex engines (not sure abut python though) will internally optimize `[^<]+<` to `(?>[^<]+)<` to avoid unnecessary backtracking.

Comment: You're right, I was going to edit it, but I figured saving 20 steps isn't crucial to the asker. Good information for other viewers though, thanks for commenting.

Answer (score 1):

```
<wrong>((?:(?!<wrong>).)*)<right>
```

You can use a negated lookahead based quantifier.See demo.

https://regex101.com/r/8yUhDL/1